# Copy Location constraint is applied to all bones in armature even though I want to apply a different constraints to each bone

Tags: armature, bones, constraints

I'm working on a project where I'm using multiple tracking points to which I want to link bones that deform a mesh. I want to use a copy location constraint to link each individual bone to a different track, but whenever I apply a copy location constraint to a bone the constraint is applied to every bone in the armature. While working earlier the constraints were applied to just the bones I had selected but for some reason now it's applying it to all of them. I've looked through various forums but haven't found an answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the tutorial I am basing my workflow off of (stage I am at is around 21:10) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNK8S19OSmA

Comment: are you sure you haven't given an Object Constraint to your armature instead of a Bone Constraint to your bone (those are 2 different tabs in the Properties panel)

Comment: Yes, you are exactly right! I'm sorry I'm an idiot, still getting used to the UI...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given an *Object Constraint* to your armature instead of a *Bone Constraint* to your bone (those are 2 different tabs in the *Properties* panel).